# How to access default value from template driven form of angular

Tags: angular

I have Created a template driven form in angular. And in that form for one input field I am getting value from another component. And I have assigned that value to the input field. I have created model also. And now I need to access that value after clicking ok button. In console I am getting empty value. How to get that dynamic value. Any help please

form.html

```
    <form name="form" #f="ngForm" class="form-horizontal">



         <div class="form-row">

            <label>Remaining qty: &nbsp;&nbsp;</label>

           <div class="form-group col-md-3">
             <input type="text" [value]="myValue"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="myModel.modelValue.value"  name="modelValue" readonly>
          </div>
        </div> 

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submit()">OK</button>
    </form>
```

form.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import { MyModel } from './myModel.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-form,
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(){
    }

  myModel: MyModel= new MyModel();
   rowData:any;

  @Input() myValue:any;


  ngOnInit() {
  }


  submit(){

    console.log(this.myModel);

}
```

form.model

```
import { BasicSearchModelI, BasicSearchKey } from '../base';

    export class myModel{

          modelValue: BasicSearchModelI = {
                value: '',
                apiKey: 'modelValue'
          };


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value attribute as well as doing two way binding, that will not work.
instead of this you can assign `myValue` in `myModel.modelValue.value` object in `ngOnInit()` method and just do two way binding as shown below

form.html

`<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="myModel.modelValue.value"  name="modelValue" readonly>`

form.ts

```
ngOnInit()
{
     myModel.modelValue.value = myValue;
}
```